# Synchronous javascript wicket

Tags: java, javascript, wicket, wicketstuff

I have a AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior that i want to make synchronous

This denied feature request is exactly what would of saved me (had it not been denied) -https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-534

**I know sync javascript is bad, however i cant live without it on this occasion.**

any ideas would be greatly appreicated, or just a working example of the "work around" shown in the link supplied above,

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `getAjaxCallDecorator()` method, to return a custom [`AjaxCallDecorator`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/calldecorator/AjaxCallDecorator.html) that decorates the javascript ajax call with some code to block the interface (to disable the form components, or display a blocking div), and decorates the the result callbacks (both onSuccess e onError) to re-enable the form.

If this must be global (all ajax requests), you may do something similar with [hooks](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/generic-busy-indicator-for-both-ajax-and-non-ajax-submits.html) in Wicket's ajax library.